# R // Combining apply with a conditioned lookup function in R // summing value in col A given that Col B and Col C fulfill requirement

Tags: r, function, datatable, conditional-statements, apply

I have a large dataset (40 Mio. rows) and would like to make 2 calculations for each row of the dataset. (1) how often has the person (with a given ID) invested before -- condition timestamp < timestamp of the given row and ID == id of the given row 
(2) what cumulative amount has the person invested at each given investment -- thus the conditions are the same as above, but summing a column called "Value" instead of counting the occurrences. 
Looping and subsetting the dataframe would be an option, but takes very long given the size of the dataset, therefore I am looking for a resource efficient solution. My attempt was to combine an apply function with a conditioned lookup, however I cannot make it work (see attempt below). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Sample Dateframe:

```
timestamp = c("2018-10-04 00:39:02", "2018-10-04 00:50:22", "2018-10-04 03:07:29", "2018-10-04 02:15:57") 
ID = c(1,1,2,3)
Value = c(100, 150, 50, 200)
sample = as.data.frame(cbind(timestamp, ID, Value))
sample$timestamp = as.POSIXct(sample$timestamp)
```

Approach via apply:

```
sample$prior_investments = apply(sample, 2, function (x) length(which(sample$ID == ID & sample$timestamp < timestamp)))
sample$invested_amount = apply(sample, 2, function (x) sum(which(sample$ID == ID & sample$timestamp < timestamp)))
```

Desired output:

```
            timestamp ID Value prior_invest invested_amount
1 2018-10-04 00:39:02  1   100       0             0
2 2018-10-04 00:50:22  1   150       1            100
3 2018-10-04 03:07:29  2    50       0             0
4 2018-10-04 02:15:57  3   200       0             0
```

Comment: Your command to create the sample should be: `sample = data.frame(timestamp, ID, Value, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, otherwise the `Values` become factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(sample)
setorder(sample, ID, timestamp)

sample[, Value := as.numeric(as.character(Value))][
  , `:=` (prior_invest = cumsum(Value > 0) - 1,
          invested_amount = cumsum(Value) - Value
          ), 
  by = ID
]
```

Output:

```
             timestamp ID Value prior_invest invested_amount
1: 2018-10-04 00:39:02  1   100            0               0
2: 2018-10-04 00:50:22  1   150            1             100
3: 2018-10-04 03:07:29  2    50            0               0
4: 2018-10-04 02:15:57  3   200            0               0
```

On the other hand, I'd rather avoid using `sample` as name of anything as it is a rather frequently used function.

Comment: Thanks, great solution: very fast and accurate!

Answer (score 1):

maybe this for your first column. Using data.table is usually a good idea when you work with very large tables.
Note that you had `apply(sample, 2, ...)` where the 2 indicates columns, but you should go by rows (1). Also the ID column is a string, so you want to use `%in%` instead of `==`

```
library(data.table)
sample <- as.data.table(sample)
sample$prior_investments = apply(sample, 1, function(x) nrow(subset(sample, ID %in% x[2] & timestamp < x[1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that a person cannot invest twice on any given second. Given that assumption, the following will return your desired output:

```
library(dplyr)

sample %>%
  arrange(ID, timestamp) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(prior_invest=row_number()-1, 
         invested_amount=cumsum(Value)-Value)
```

---

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
  timestamp              ID Value prior_invest invested_amount
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>
1 2018-10-04 00:39:02     1   100            0               0
2 2018-10-04 00:50:22     1   150            1             100
3 2018-10-04 03:07:29     2    50            0               0
4 2018-10-04 02:15:57     3   200            0               0
```